# Image Source (src) when passed to Reusable-Component does not show image in UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I have added an image in the `public` folder of React-Project. Now, when I want to show an image - it gets showed up in a component, but if I try to pass its url and show the image in some `reusable component` - I find that image is not shown in UI.

Can someone help me out?

**Home.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Cards from './cards';

class Home1 extends Component {

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <img src="img/aishwarya.jpg" />
        <Cards title="Aishwarya" sourcelink="img/aishwarya.png" details="Miss World 1994" />
      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default Home1;
```

**Cards.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './cards.css';

const Cards = (props) => {

  return (
    <div className="cardHolder">
      <div className="imageHolder">
        <img src={props.sourcelink} />
      </div>
      <div className="contentHolder">
        <h3>{props.title}</h3>
        <p>{props.details}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );

}

export default Cards;
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When using `webpack`, for images under `src`, a path like `img/aishwarya.jpg` is only available **during build time**.

You need to import it, see [Adding Images, Fonts, and Files](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/):

```
import image from "./img/aishwarya.jpg";
console.log(image) // /aishwarya.84287d09.jpg

<img src={image} />
<img src={require("img/aishwarya.jpg")} />
```

See working example:

[image: Edit interesting-smoke-zv0pv]